# error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in admob

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I tried many combination but it showing following error in xml file

> error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

in `<com.google.ads.AdView` line, how can i resolve this.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        >
        <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" > 
    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            myapp:adUnitId="000000000000000"
            myapp:adSize="BANNER"
            myapp:refreshInterval="30"
         />
        </RelativeLayout>
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_of_wishes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:dividerHeight="2dip"

            android:clickable="true" >
               </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: myapp doesn't have a namespace declaration

Comment: xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lilakhelait.kishordgupta.mainscreenactivity" 
i add that line but still same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd like to think that you should be using the `ads:` instead of `myapp:`, but I might be wrong. Let me know if this doesn't work for you:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="000000000000000"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:refreshInterval="30"
     />
```

The reason for this possibly helping would be the fact that you've set an `ads` namespace, but not `myapp` (as seen in this line):

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Comment: i am sorry, i cant understand ur solve i used ads , m be i understand u wrong

Comment: <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="000000000000000"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:refreshInterval="30"
     /> 

i used that but same error

Comment: xmlns:myapp="schemas.android.com/apk/res/…; i add that line but still same error –

Comment: Thanks i solve it, i just to declare myapp in second layout thank you